# Limit, in distribution, of random variable defined for each n

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, random-variable

For each $n \in N $, let $X_n$ a random variable with probability distribution:

$$P(X_n = j) = \frac{2j}{n(n+1)}$$

With $j = 1,\dots,n$

I need to find:

a) Cumulative distribution Function of the random variable $Yn = X_n/n$

b) Limit, in distribution, of the sequence $(Y_n)_{n \ge 1}$

For a) I was trying just integrating it:

$P(Y_n \le j) = P(X \le nj) = \int_{1}^{nj}\frac{2j}{n(n+1)} dj = \frac{n}{n+1} (j^2 - 1)$

For the distribution, just derive a):

$\frac{d P(Y_n \le j)}{dj} = 2j \frac{n}{n+1}$

Now, how should I proceed to work b)? When $n \to \infty$ it should look like a known distribution? Have I made a mistake in a)?

Comment: When $j \ge 2$, your probabilities in your solution to $(a)$ are obviously greater than $1$.  In $(b)$, pick any $j$: what happens to $\Pr(Y_n=j)$ as $n$ increases?

Comment: Now your probabilities are negative!

Comment: This transformation is making me very confused. I'm trying $P(X \le nj) = \int_{n}^{nj}\frac{2j}{n(n+1)}$, but this evaluates to $\frac{n(j^2 - 1)}{n-1}$, which still doesnt make sense. The boundaries of j before the transformation were 1 and n, so they should be n and n^2 after it. For example, if I was just doing without a transformation it would be: $P(X \le j) = \int_{1}^{j}\frac{2j}{n(n+1)} = \frac{j^2 - 1}{n(n-1)}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cumulative distribution function for $X_n$:

$$F_{X_n}(j) = \sum_{i=1}^{j}\frac{2i}{n(n+1)} = \frac{j(j+1)}{n(n+1)}$$

The cum. distr. funct. for $Y_n$:

$$F_{Y_n}(k = \frac{j}{n}) = \frac{j(j+1)}{n(n+1)} = \frac{n^2\frac{j}{n}(\frac{j}{n}+\frac{1}{n})}{n(n+1)} = \frac{nk(k+\frac{1}{n})}{n+1}$$

keeping in mind $k \in [0,1]$ and taking the limit $n \to \infty$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}F_{Y_n}(k) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{nk^2+k}{n+1}= k^2$$

Comment: Is this an answer to the OP's question? It it a hint? (Please only provide hints for `[self-study]` questions.) Can you elaborate this?

Comment: Damn, just noticed I was trying to integrate a discrete random variable, that's why no result made any sense. I feel so dumb for that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @gung I'm new, so I didn't know [self-study] only requires hints no answers

Comment: No problem, @user118591, now you know. You can read more about our `[self-study]` policies (which are special & unique to SS) [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Welcome to CV.

Comment: Just a question, is $k \in [0,1]$? Shouldn't it be $k \in [1/n,1]$?

Comment: indeed you are correct but in the limit it goes to $k\in[0,1]$

Comment: @user118591 I don't get why it's possible to set `k = j /n` and then not take it into account when making `n` go infinity.

Comment: You can think of $X_6$ as a unfair (it follows given probability density) 6 sided dice. $Y_6$ is the same 6 sided dice but the sides are 1/6, 2/6, ...,1. Here it is obvious that the probability of getting a 1 with dice $X_6$ is the same as getting 1/6 with the $Y_6$ dice. Taking the limit like using dice with more sides.

Comment: @cd98 ignore my previous comment.

Comment: @cd98 when taking the limit I only need the distribution function of $Y_n$ so its relation to the distribution of $X_n$ is no longer of any meaning

Comment: @user118591 I think my question doesn't have to do with $X_n$ at all. Just considering $Y_n$, the expression has $k$ defined as $\frac{j}{n}$. Later you take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$, but take $k$ as fixed, as it didn't depend on $n$. I'm wondering what allows you to do that. If it's something you deem basic, please feel free to ignore it. Otherwise, please incorporate it to the question as other readers might have my same question, thanks :)